# Windows 7 Sticky Notes On A Per-Folder Basis

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

Is there any way to stick notes to specific folders rather than getting to view them from Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the included **Sticky Notes** app, but it's possible with something like [**Stickies**](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/):

[image: 1]

> - Once on screen, stickies will remain where placed until closed, even through reboots
> - Stickies appearance can be customised; fonts, colours and buttons may be changed, and styles saved. Stickies can be resized
> - Stickies can store text or images
> - Stickies can snap to each other and to the sides of the screen to keep them neatly lined up
> - Stickies can be attached to a web site, document or folder so they only show when it's on screen
> - Stickies can be transferred from one machine to another either over a TCP/IP network connection, or by using an SMTP mail server or MAPI client:
>
>   - Hierarchical friends list, which may be automatically transferred from other friends
>   - Play a sound file on receive
>   - Signature for transmitted or emailed stickies
>   - Favourite friends, and custom lists can be made
> - Stickies can be hidden for a certain period, until a specified date and time, or to wake every day, week or month, to act as reminders
> - Stickies can have alarms set to ensure you notice them at a point you choose
> - International language, Unicode and RTL text support
> - Stickies works with Windows Vista and Windows 7
> - Stickies is small and simple, it writes to a single text file, and does not alter the registry
> - AD network administrators can use Group Policy to control settings
> - API to allow integration with other applications
> - ...and Stickies is completely free!

As mentioned above, stickies can be attached to a web site, document, folder or basically any app window:

[image: 2]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't seem to be able to see my Stickies when I open the folder to which they were attached.

Comment: The sticky's probably being displayed, but *behind* the folder window. Here's what I did: created a new sticky, then clicked the [**Toggle On Top** arrow](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I1VeN.png). and next I attached it to an open folder (`C:\Windows` in [this case](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TviFC.png)). Now even if I close the Explorer window, whenever I open `C:\Windows` directly or even navigate to it, the sticky immediately pops up. Try it and let me know.