# Changing fonts of StickyNotes

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

Is there any way to change and set the different font for Windows Sticky Notes ??? I have gone through the following link.

[How do I change the default font of Sticky Notes?](https://superuser.com/questions/35589/how-do-i-change-the-default-font-of-sticky-notes)

According to the link, I can change my default font, but there is no way I can change and set the font which I want. I need it as copy-pasting fonts each time is not a proper solution.

Comment: Switch to a better app such as [this one](http://superuser.com/a/564998/138343). Other than copy-pasting from other apps I don't think there's a solution for the in-built feature, which is quite basic in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses Segoe Print font as default in the Sticky Note.
You can change the default font in the Sticky Note as follows:

1. Click `Start` (i.e., the Windows logo in the corner where the `Start` button used to be).
2. Select `Run...`
3. Type "regedit".
4. Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`.
5. In the right pane, Find "Segoe Print (TrueType)" and "Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)" - double-click (don't forget to change both - one by one).
   Optional - you can delete other Segoe fonts -
   select (one click), press <kbd>Delete</kbd>, press `Yes`.
6. Change the value (double-click on font) to the file name of any other font that you wish to use that is already installed - for "Times New Roman" it should be `times.ttf`.
7. Restart the computer.